# Handlebars to loop through array of objects and create a list with unlimited sublists

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have an array that looks like this:

```
  var menuItems = [
      {
        title: "title1",
        link: "link1",
        subMenu: [
          {
            title: "subMenu1",
            link: "subMenuLink1",
            subMenu: [
              {
                title: "subSubMenu1",
                link: "subSubLink1"
              },
              {
                title: "subSubMenu2",
                link: "subSubLink2"
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            title: "subMenu2",
            link: "subMenuLink2"
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "title1",
        link: "link1"
      },
      {
        title: "title1",
        link: "link1"
      },
      {
        title: "title1",
        link: "link1"
      }
  ]
```

And each item can have an as many submenus as desired. I want to loop through this and create a list in HTML with nested lists to reflect the data. Like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">title1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">subMenu1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">subSubMenu1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">subSubMenu2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">subMenu1</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have the following:

```
  {{#each this}}
    <li>
        <a>
          {{this.title}}
        </a>
        {{#if subMenu}}
          <ul>
            {{#each subMenu}}
              <li>
                  <a>
                    {{title}}
                  </a>
              </li>
            {{/each}}
          </ul>
        {{/if}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
```

But this wouldn't be able to support anything past 2 subMenu levels. If anyone could help me with this, or point me in the right direction on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a partial template, let's call it submenu:

```
<li>
    {{this.title}}
    {{#if subMenu}}
        {{#each subMenu}}
        <ul>
            {{> submenu}}
        </ul>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
</li>
```

And then in your main template:

```
<ul>
{{#each this}}
    {{> submenu}}
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

You’ll need to register your partial:

```
Handlebars.registerPartial('submenu', Handlebars.templates.submenu);
```